# button should disable when last color is visible?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to disable **next button** when the last div is visible or last div  hasclass "activeNavLi". But with the help of this code it is not disabling, and button removing and adding first and next class to the element.

```js
    $('.picker-wrapper__colors .colorOuter:lt(5)').addClass('activeNavLi');
    $(".rightArrow").click(function() {
        if ($('.colorOuter:last').is(':visible')) {
            $('.rightArrow').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        if ($('.colorOuter').last().not('activeNavLi')) {
            $('.colorOuter.activeNavLi').first().removeClass('activeNavLi');
            $('.colorOuter.activeNavLi').next().addClass('activeNavLi');
        }
    });
    $(".leftArrow").click(function() {
        if (jQuery('.colorOuter:first').is(':visible')) {
            jQuery('.leftArrow').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        $('.colorOuter.activeNavLi').last().removeClass('activeNavLi');
        $('.colorOuter.activeNavLi').prev().addClass('activeNavLi');
    });
```

```css
    .picker-wrapper__colors {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .colorOuter {
        margin: 0 10px;
        display: none;
    }
    
    .hideDiv {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .activeNavLi {
        display: inline-block;
        border: 2px solid #999;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<button class="leftArrow colorArrows">
    <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        size="35" height="35" width="35" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M15.41 7.41L14 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41L10.83 12z"></path>
    </svg>
</button>
<div class="colorSlider picker-wrapper__colors">
    <div class="colorOuter">
        <img ng-src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Green.png" ng-click="selectExterior(car.exterior.color_name_en, car.exterior.car_image_1, car.exterior.color_name_en)" src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Green.png">
    </div>

    <div class="colorOuter">
        <img ng-src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_LBlue.png" ng-click="selectExterior(car.exterior.color_name_en, car.exterior.car_image_1, car.exterior.color_name_en)" src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_LBlue.png">
    </div>

    <div class="colorOuter">
        <img ng-src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Black.png" ng-click="selectExterior(car.exterior.color_name_en, car.exterior.car_image_1, car.exterior.color_name_en)" src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Black.png">
    </div>

    <div class="colorOuter">
        <img ng-src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Red.png" ng-click="selectExterior(car.exterior.color_name_en, car.exterior.car_image_1, car.exterior.color_name_en)" src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Red.png">
    </div>

    <div class="colorOuter">
        <img ng-src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_LRed.png" ng-click="selectExterior(car.exterior.color_name_en, car.exterior.car_image_1, car.exterior.color_name_en)" src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_LRed.png">
    </div>
    <div class="colorOuter">
        <img ng-src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Brown.png" ng-click="selectExterior(car.exterior.color_name_en, car.exterior.car_image_1, car.exterior.color_name_en)" src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Brown.png">
    </div>

    <div class="colorOuter">
        <img ng-src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Orange.png" ng-click="selectExterior(car.exterior.color_name_en, car.exterior.car_image_1, car.exterior.color_name_en)" src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Orange.png">
    </div>

    <div class="colorOuter">
        <img ng-src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Yellow.png" ng-click="selectExterior(car.exterior.color_name_en, car.exterior.car_image_1, car.exterior.color_name_en)" src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Yellow.png">
    </div>

    <div class="colorOuter">
        <img ng-src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Silver.png" ng-click="selectExterior(car.exterior.color_name_en, car.exterior.car_image_1, car.exterior.color_name_en)" src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Silver.png">
    </div>

    <div class="colorOuter">
        <img ng-src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Grey.png" ng-click="selectExterior(car.exterior.color_name_en, car.exterior.car_image_1, car.exterior.color_name_en)" src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Grey.png">
    </div>
</div>
<button class="rightArrow colorArrows">
    <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        size="35" height="35" width="35" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z"></path>
    </svg>
</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try toggling disabled on both arrow buttons

```js
$('.picker-wrapper__colors .colorOuter:lt(5)').addClass('activeNavLi');

$(".rightArrow").click(function() {
  if ($('.colorOuter').last().not('activeNavLi')) {
    $('.colorOuter.activeNavLi').first().removeClass('activeNavLi');
    $('.colorOuter.activeNavLi').next().addClass('activeNavLi');
  }
  $('.rightArrow').prop('disabled', $('.colorOuter:last').is(':visible'));
  $('.leftArrow').prop('disabled', $('.colorOuter:first').is(':visible'));
});

$(".leftArrow").click(function() {
  $('.colorOuter.activeNavLi').last().removeClass('activeNavLi');
  $('.colorOuter.activeNavLi').prev().addClass('activeNavLi');
  $('.leftArrow').prop('disabled', $('.colorOuter:first').is(':visible'));
  $('.rightArrow').prop('disabled', $('.colorOuter:last').is(':visible'));
});
```

```css
.picker-wrapper__colors {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.colorOuter {
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: none;
}

.hideDiv {
  display: none;
}

.activeNavLi {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button class="leftArrow colorArrows" disabled>
    <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        size="35" height="35" width="35" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M15.41 7.41L14 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41L10.83 12z"></path>
    </svg>
</button>
<div class="colorSlider picker-wrapper__colors">
  <div class="colorOuter">
    <img ng-src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Green.png" ng-click="selectExterior(car.exterior.color_name_en, car.exterior.car_image_1, car.exterior.color_name_en)" src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Green.png">
  </div>

  <div class="colorOuter">
    <img ng-src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_LBlue.png" ng-click="selectExterior(car.exterior.color_name_en, car.exterior.car_image_1, car.exterior.color_name_en)" src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_LBlue.png">
  </div>

  <div class="colorOuter">
    <img ng-src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Black.png" ng-click="selectExterior(car.exterior.color_name_en, car.exterior.car_image_1, car.exterior.color_name_en)" src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Black.png">
  </div>

  <div class="colorOuter">
    <img ng-src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Red.png" ng-click="selectExterior(car.exterior.color_name_en, car.exterior.car_image_1, car.exterior.color_name_en)" src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Red.png">
  </div>

  <div class="colorOuter">
    <img ng-src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_LRed.png" ng-click="selectExterior(car.exterior.color_name_en, car.exterior.car_image_1, car.exterior.color_name_en)" src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_LRed.png">
  </div>
  <div class="colorOuter">
    <img ng-src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Brown.png" ng-click="selectExterior(car.exterior.color_name_en, car.exterior.car_image_1, car.exterior.color_name_en)" src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Brown.png">
  </div>

  <div class="colorOuter">
    <img ng-src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Orange.png" ng-click="selectExterior(car.exterior.color_name_en, car.exterior.car_image_1, car.exterior.color_name_en)" src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Orange.png">
  </div>

  <div class="colorOuter">
    <img ng-src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Yellow.png" ng-click="selectExterior(car.exterior.color_name_en, car.exterior.car_image_1, car.exterior.color_name_en)" src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Yellow.png">
  </div>

  <div class="colorOuter">
    <img ng-src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Silver.png" ng-click="selectExterior(car.exterior.color_name_en, car.exterior.car_image_1, car.exterior.color_name_en)" src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Silver.png">
  </div>

  <div class="colorOuter">
    <img ng-src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Grey.png" ng-click="selectExterior(car.exterior.color_name_en, car.exterior.car_image_1, car.exterior.color_name_en)" src="https://cdn.assetrepository.me/images/Swatch_Grey.png">
  </div>
</div>
<button class="rightArrow colorArrows">
    <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        size="35" height="35" width="35" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z"></path>
    </svg>
</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```